# My screen says UEFI but windows says "Legacy" for BIOS - Which am I using?

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I have a computer that right now is only configured to use Windows 10.  It was originally installed running 8.1 and then upgraded to 10.

I am trying to figure out if I am using BIOS or UEFI on this machine.

The method [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/29504-bios-mode-see-if-windows-boot-uefi-legacy-mode.html) and [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/home_is_where_i_lay_my_head/2012/10/02/how-to-check-in-windows-if-you-are-using-uefi/) (using Windows built in utilities) seem to show that my computer is using BIOS (see image below and note **legacy** next to BIOS mode):

[image]

However, when booting this is my "BIOS Screen" which says UEFI all over it:

[image]

Can someone tell me definitely how to check - or how I should know?

Comment: You obviously have CSM/Legacy Mode enabled

Answer (score 3):

I can't see EFI on the screenshot, I am guessing that is just a stock image by the watermark - can you please take a picture of yours?

If Windows says legacy mode, I believe you are booting in to a legacy/non EFI based system

Another way to test and confirm is to go to `Disk Management` (Windows Key + x, then k).

By default, you should have either a 100MB or 350MB system reserved partition. This should be marked as `System, Active, Primary` on a legacy/bios machine, or `EFI System Partition` on an EFI based system

[image]

Comment: I couldn't take a screen shot of the BIOS because print-screen wasn't working.  That is a stock image but it is the same bios screen as mine.

Comment: I have a 350MB NTFS "system reserved" partion that is, as you said, marked as Healthy `System, Active, Primary` so this must be legacy?  Is there some way to switch this after the fact? I also thought Windows 10 only supported UEFI

Comment: @Startec  Windows 10 supports both, otherwise my "old faithful" machine wouldn't work. What won't work is a GPT boot disk on a BIOS system or an MBR boot disk on a UEFI system, they are unsupported configurations. There seems to be a clearer way to see the disk type at http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/268934-32-disk but be careful not to do anything harmful.